# Look up a list of values in the ranges (bins) as defined by two columns in another table and get the corresponding value from the third column

Tags: sql, join, hiveql

Hello I have two tables T1 and T2. T1 has a column of integer values. And T2 has ranges defined by two columns and a corresponding value for each range... Something like this:

```
range_min range_max  corr_value
   5         10         1020
   11        15         5000
```

Suppose I want to be able to get the "value" from T2 for each integer of T1 depending on which range the integer value falls into. Say, I have 6, 7, and 12 in T1. Then, the ideal result would look like this:

```
integer_val  corr_value
     6          1020
     7          1020
     12         5000
```

Note that I don't have anything to join on. I couldn't figure out how to do this using SQL. I don't know if it'll make a difference, but I am using HiveQL.

I really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You can use a non-equijoin. If your SQL supports `between`, use

```
select t1.integer_val, t2.corr_value
from t1
left outer join t2 on t1.integer_val between t2.range_min and t2.range_max
```

Otherwise, use

```
select t1.integer_val, t2.corr_value
from t1
left outer join t2 on t1.integer_val >= t2.range_min and t1.integer_val <= t2.range_max
```

[Here is a reference to a mysql demo on sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d5b8/2)

This query works as you describe only when there are no overlaps in the `t1`.

Comment: I see no reason for an outer join.

Comment: @DanBracuk Using an outer join eliminates questions of "where did my numbers go?" sort when there numbers in `t2` for which there is no corresponding range in `t1`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight -- I edited your great answer slightly -- Dan -- left join ensures the integer will be returned with a corr value or at minimum, with a NULL value.

Comment: @user1621315 It looks like you are running against a limitation of hive DB: [Only equality joins, outer joins, and left semi joins are supported in Hive. Hive does not support join conditions that are not equality conditions as it is very difficult to express such conditions as a map/reduce job.](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-joins.html). It does not look like you can pull it off with hivesql. Can you expand `t1` to have a row for every value in the range?

Comment: Thanks guys, this was really helpful. And yes I think I ran against the HiveQL limitation. Any ideas as to how I can write this query differently or do something more fundamental with data?

Comment: @user1621315 Can you add a row for each number in the range? For example, instead of `{5,10,1020}` add `{5, 1020}, {6, 1020}, {7, 1020}, {8, 1020}, {9, 1020}, {10, 1020}`?

Comment: Yes, I think that's what we're going to do. :) Though, there might be some UDF (User Defined Function) type of solutions, but this seems more straightforward for our purposes. Thanks again. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
select integer_val, corr_value
from t1 join t2 on integer_val >= range_min
and integer_val >= range_max
```